# Is it possible to GRANT permission for just UPDATE?

Tags: cassandra

According to the [Cassandra docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/grant_r.html), the MODIFY permissions allows full write permissions (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE). I need to be able to specify just some of them, in this case, just UPDATE.

Is there some way to only allow UPDATE?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of CQL packaged in Cassandra 2.0 and below do not allow for UPDATE only.  This is partially because it wouldn't really be possible.  An UPDATE with a TTL is the same as a DELETE.  INSERT and UPDATE are essentially the same thing.